# Kotlin compiler doesnt recognize variable as non-null even after implicit check

Tags: kotlin, null

I have a piece of code that parses and arbitrary document.

```
if (page.title != null && page.text != null && page.timestamp != null && size != null) {
    parseTitle(page.title)
    parseText(page.text)
}
```

Despite the implicit null checks, compiler still says that page.title and page.text are both nullable.

Can someone explain why that happens?

Comment: Are any of these `var`?

Comment: they are all var's, yeah

Comment: See the last paragraph in this section: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions

Comment: I’ll just comment since I know this question is a duplicate but I’m on mobile so it’s hard to search quickly. If `page` is a property rather than local variable or if `title` and `text` are mutable properties (`var`), then it’s possible for their values to have changed in between the null check and the next time you access them, so the compiler cannot assume they are non-null. Copy their values to local variables first and then null-check and use those local variables.

Comment: Also, those null checks are explicit, the opposite of implicit :)